# Show list data based specific filter in Laravel Backpack

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have listed products like this
[image: List Products]

And I want only to show specific data with the category `eraser`.

I tried to query it and this is my attempt.
[image: Attempt]

Code in my ProductCrudController

```
protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('name');
        // CRUD::column('category_id')->type('select');
        CRUD::column('created_at');
        CRUD::column('updated_at');

        $this->crud->addColumn([
            'label'         => 'Category',
            'type'          => 'select',
            'name'          => 'category_id',
            'entity'        => 'category',
            'attribute'     => 'name'
        ]);

    }
```

Code in my Product Models

```
public function category()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->where('id', 1);
 }
```

How do I do that to show data with a specific filter?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to permanent filter the query you can use "Custom Query" as is describe in our documentation https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-list-entries#custom-query-1 if you want to give user option to filter it, you need to use our filters, in this case i suggest to you "select2_ajax" https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-filters#select2_ajax-1

Cheers

Comment: Hi @Jorge, I tried with this approaching, here my code: 
`$this->crud->addClause('join', 'categories', function($join) { 
$join->on('products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')->where('categories.id', '=', 1)
->selectRaw('products.*'); });`
I got what I want, but the column name became the same value with category, and URL for edit also wrong, like the id should be 8 became 1. I still tried to figuring out, but now
I'll stick with search input for filtering. Thanks.